# How to get the survey activated dateTime from limesurvey API

Tags: limesurvey

I need to get the survey activated time from limesurvey API (http://api.limesurvey.org/classes/remotecontrol_handle.html) But I couldn't find a method to retrieve the activated time.

Can you pleases let me know how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

http://api.limesurvey.org/classes/remotecontrol_handle.html#method_get_survey_properties

You can get : startdate, but there are no "activated time" in limesurvey, only datecreated .